# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed -- What IP's do i need to target?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

This is my first time posting, and I'm in a difficult situation i'd consider somewhat unique.

**My Goal and Whats happened so far**:

Basically, I just need to pass integers from my desktop PC to a raspberry pi in "real time", preferably over a wireless connection. The code snippets below are versions of the "test program" that employ specifically what I'm having issues with. To achieve this, I'm using the python [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) module

The issue I'm facing is new to me, because previously this program worked entirely as intended, as I lived in a location where I owned my router in a house, but now I live in an apartment complex with special network restrictions (needing to register MAC addresses and such)

**Previous Results (When I lived at the previous location)**

I achieved the desired results of pasting random integers to the console as fast as possible that were generated from the server PC with the following programs below. Note that when I put  i used the IP that could be easily found when you google "what is my IP"

SERVER SIDE (ON THE PC)

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import random


async def createdata():
    return random.randint(0, 15000)


async def senddata(websocket, path):
    number = await createdata()
    print("sending data")
    await websocket.send(str(number))
    print(number)


start_server = websockets.serve(senddata, "<INSERTIPHERE>", 4421)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

CLIENT SIDE (ON THE RASP PI)

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def datarecieve():
    uri = "ws://<INSERTIPHERE>:4421"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        print(data)

while True:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(datarecieve())
```

**Results Now (Now that I live in the apartment complex)**

I get the error thrown on the client side: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed (ipgoeshere, port). Here are the programs:

SERVER SIDE (ON THE PC)

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import random


async def createdata():
    return random.randint(0, 15000)


async def senddata(websocket, path):
    number = await createdata()
    print("sending data")
    await websocket.send(str(number))
    print(number)


start_server = websockets.serve(senddata, "localhost", 4421)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

CLIENT SIDE (ON THE RASP PI)

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def datarecieve():
    uri = "ws://<externalipofappartmentcomplex>:4421"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        print(data)

while True:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(datarecieve())
```

**More Information About What I've Tried or What I'm Willing to Do**

- For the server side, I've also tried ips like: 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, and the ipv4 assigned to the device (found in ipconfig in cmd)
- For the Client side, I've also tried the ipv4 assigned to the server device
- Opening up the port on the firewall of the server computer
- I've considered just buying my own wireless router and hopefully finding luck that way

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why `websockets.serve(senddata, "localhost", 4421)` should that not be websockets.serve(senddata, "<externalipofappartmentcomplex>", 4421)

Comment: @Heinz because when i try the external IP of the apartment complex I get an error thrown by the server saying "it cannot be bound to". I dont have the specific error message on hand right now.